# struggling to find a way to monitor CPU and GPU, either third party or using code

Tags: performance, gpu, cpu, directx-10

so I'm currently working on a method to evaluate some graphics programming techniques in direct x 10, specifically custom shader files and instancing but I need a method of evaluating just how efficient it is to use them. I've been trying to find a way to evaluate it using draw speed, CPU load and GPU load as in theory there should be a much more rapid draw speed and the CPU & GPU load will be reduced as the program increases in efficiency.
My question is there a decent 3rd party method to monitor GPU & CPU or is it better to code manually, I'm using the rastertek framework currently.

Answer (score 0):

DirectX has profiling tools already available..

i.e. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj585574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) according to google ;-)